# Reduce white space margin in cowplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

Data and libraries used for this question:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(cowplot)
data("diamonds")
temp1_m <- temp2_m <- melt(diamonds[1:3])
temp1_m[3] <- temp2_m[3] <- NULL
colnames(temp1_m) <- colnames(temp2_m) <- c('Var1', 'Var2', 'value')
```

I'm trying to combine two `geom_tile` plots using the `cowplot` library.
The two individual plots are created using:

```
figMT <- ggplot(temp2_m, aes(Var1, Var2))+
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = 'white')+
    scale_fill_gradient(low = 'green', high = 'red', name = 'log fold change',
    guide = guide_legend(title.vjust = 1, reverse = T))+
    ggtitle('Mutant clusters')+
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))+
    scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(temp2_m$Var2)))+
    xlab('')+
    ylab('')+
    coord_equal()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    axis.text = element_text(size=12),plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))
```

and

```
figWT <- ggplot(temp1_m, aes(Var1, Var2))+
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value), colour = 'white')+
    scale_fill_gradient(low = 'green', high = 'red', name = 'log fold change',
    guide = guide_legend(title.vjust = 1, reverse = T))+
    ggtitle('WT clusters')+
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0, 0))+
    scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(temp1_m$Var2)))+
    xlab('')+
    ylab('Cluster')+
    coord_equal()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
    axis.text = element_text(size=12),plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,0,0,0), "mm"))
```

I then use `cowplot` to first make a title with:

```
title <- ggdraw()+
  draw_label("Heatmaps over the average fold change of the clusters", fontface='bold')
```

and then to combine the title and the two plots with:

```
p <- plot_grid(figWT+ theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, -10, 0, 0), "cm")),
               figMT+ theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, -5.1), "cm")),
               labels=c('A', 'B'), hjust = c(-24, -.5))
plot_grid(title, p, nrow=2, rel_heights=c(0.1, 1))
```

I reduce a lot of whitespace between the two heatmaps after moving them closer together. But it creates a lot of whitespaces on the left and right margin which I don't manage to remove. That is, when I save the picture with:

```
ggsave('ex1.pdf', scale = 2)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

By adding `coord_equal()`, you're setting a fixed-aspect-ratio coordinate system, which means you need to make the aspect ratio of the final output file match the aspect ratios of your underlying plots. By not specifying a width and a height in your `ggsave()` line you're essentially guaranteed to not get the right output. Also, if you find yourself setting large negative margins you know for sure you're doing something wrong.

Without knowing exactly what the intended output is, this seems reasonable to me:

```
p <- plot_grid(figWT, figMT, labels=c('A', 'B'))
plot_grid(title, p, nrow=2, rel_heights=c(0.1, 1))
ggsave("ex1.png", width = 8, height = 4.5, dpi = 300)
```

[image]